# How can I configure Prettier to produce same result as a js-beautify config?

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, prettier, js-beautify

How can I configure Prettier to produce this same result?

`js-beautify -r -n -u -b collapse,preserve-inline "$@"`

This is what I currently have in my `.prettierrc`

````
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "tabWidth": 4
}```
````

Comment: I'm confused about your question: what kind of formatting are you looking to achieve? Could you give us an example of intended and actual formatting that you're having trouble with achieving? You can find a list of all the supported Prettier options [in their documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-spacing). Note that Prettier was intentionally made to support only a select few options — see [Prettier's option philosophy](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html)

Comment: @EmmaKoskinen I want to know what the equivalent of ```"brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline"``` and ```break_chained_methods: false``` is with prettier and eslint